# Chrome keeps chrashing a short while after startup

Tags: google-chrome

whenever I turn on Chrome, it crashes after a very short while (less than a minute). It started happening about a week ago for no apparent reason. I didn't install any new software, update or uninstall anything (as far as I remember), it just crashes. It doesn't matter wether I even open any page or not, Chrome just dies, period.

Doesn't anybody have an idea why might that be?
I'm running on Windows Vista Home Basic.

Comment: Uninstall Chrome, reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Or switch to a more recent version. The Beta channel may be more stable for you. http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel (Just remember to switch back in a month or so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Moab mentioned your safest bet is to uninstall and then reinstall Chrome.

If regular uninstalling doesn't work, completely remove anything Chrome related. Go to App Data in your Windows profile `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\` and delete the folders there. Do you want to be really sure? Run CCleaner to remove whatever temp-files and cached stuff might be left behind.

As long as you are logged in to Chrome, all your settings should be synced (unless you turned it off) so after reinstalling and setting up the syncing again, you should have all your settings back too.

Most likely there were some flags (check about:flags) turned on that might conflict with one of your extensions. So just to be sure, check about:flags before setting up syncing and make sure they're all turned off. That's the best way to be sure that the problem is not caused by Chrome

Comment: I will try that and post the result. Thank you.

Comment: Well, this did NOT help.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using @cypher and come into the Root Access chatroom, so we can figure out what info we're missing

Comment: 8.0.552.224, I'm coming.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses would be.

- Uninstall chrome.
- Reboot
- Install the [portable version of chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)

That will take a corrupt registry key or some other OS issue that is left behind a possible corrupt installation and incomplete uninstallation.

The other thing I wonder is what webpage are you trying to open. Is your homepage part of the problem?